# Processing a PDF for information extraction

Tags: python, html, pdf, nltk, information-retrieval

I am working on a project where I have a pdf file which describes one of the health policy. What I need to do is extract the information from this PDF and try to save it in some form such that I can answer the questions related to the policy by extracting info from this PDf.

This PDF is too big, so I want to divide the PDF according to the different sections so that when a query related to some particular area comes in then I wont have to go through the entire document.

I tried solving this using some pdf converters which converts the PDFs into the HTMLs. But these converters wont convert the PDF to HTML properly so that headings will have heading tag. Also even if I convert this properly and get the proper sections out of the document, I am not getting how to store this data.(I mean in which form should I store this Data).

Is there any other solution with which I can achieve this. I am using Python and also I can use NLTK if needed. Also the format is not fixed for the PDfs, I mean to say my code should work on any kind of PDFs.

Comment: The scope of this problem is probably a little too large. There are companies working full-time on this problem, and they haven't solved it perfectly yet (as you found) and I doubt they ever will, given that PDF's strength isn't exactly structured data storage.

Comment: Thankz for the reply. we are working on the same thing. But actually stuck from where to start and how to do it. If you got any advice for this problem. Please help me out. :)

Comment: I would try and see if the information you are looking for can be found somewhere more upstream (before it turned into a PDF).

Comment: PDFbox (http://pdfbox.apache.org) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) is great in that it has location for every bit of text it gets from the PDF. It won't be nicely put in header tags or anything like that, but if you have a consistent PDF structure in your docs you might be able to get something working.

Comment: thankz :) I tried the PDFminer, it works fine for text but does it work fine for tables also?